# How to make 2 different executables using 2 different main.cpp files when using CMake only once?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I have a graphics project that requires a 2d editor and a 3d editor.  I have a different `main.cpp` file for each one containing the code to run the program.  How do I get the two different executables to be made when I run `cmake ..` and then `make`?  Do I need to add something to the CMakeLists.txt file?

This is the CMakeLists.txt file that I have:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(Assignment2)

### Output directories
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")

### Compilation flags: adapt to your needs ###
if(MSVC)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /MP /bigobj") ### Enable parallel compilation
  set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
  set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} )
else()
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
endif()

### Add src to the include directories
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")

### Include Eigen for linear algebra
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/eigen")

### Compile GLFW3 statically
set(GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL " " FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL " " FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_DOCS OFF CACHE BOOL " " FORCE)
set(GLFW_BUILD_INSTALL OFF CACHE BOOL " " FORCE)
add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/glfw" "glfw")
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/glfw/include")
set(LIBRARIES "glfw" ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})

### On windows, you also need glew
if((UNIX AND NOT APPLE) OR WIN32)
  set(GLEW_INSTALL OFF CACHE BOOL " " FORCE)
  add_subdirectory("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/glew" "glew")
  include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/glew/include")
  list(APPEND LIBRARIES "glew")
endif()

### Compile all the cpp files in src
file(GLOB SOURCES
"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp"
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_bin ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_bin ${LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Make two `add_executable()` calls.

Comment: So, add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_bin ${SOURCES})
      add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_bin2 ${SOURCES})  Or no need to rename the last "bin"?

Comment: The first parameter of `add_executable` is also the name of the file to create, so yes. You will probably want a different set of source files, too, otherwise you end up with the same program twice ;)

Answer (score 1):

As commented, if you want two executables, you should call the [`add_executable()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html) command **twice**. Since you have two main.cpp files, you can call `add_executable()` for each one, while still adding your other remaining source files to *both* executables.

Also, the use of the `file(GLOB ...)` command is not recommended, because CMake cannot track changes to your set of source files. Instead, you should list out your source files individually. Your CMake could look something like this:

```
set(SOURCES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MyClass1.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MyClass2.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MyHelperFunctions.cpp
)

# Call add_executable() for each main.cpp file.
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_bin_2d 
    ${SOURCES}
    main_2d.cpp
)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_bin_3d 
    ${SOURCES}
    main_3d.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_bin_2d ${LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_bin_3d ${LIBRARIES})
```